# Doxygen wrongly include mainpage sections written in markdown in the first modules sections

Tags: doxygen

Given the following two files, and a doxygen configuration file with `GENERATE_TREEVIEW = YES`

Introduction.txt

```
/**
\mainpage Introduction.
Not to be inserted into modules
### First part  
this first part of the introduction
talks about \ref GroupA
### Second part
This is the second part
*/
```

A.h

```
/**
 \defgroup GroupA
 \brief Module definition
*/

/**
\ingroup GroupA
\brief this is the A class
 Class A is the first class
*/
class A { int a;/** central element */ };
```

When I build the documentation of these files with doxygen, I get the following unexpected treeview:

[image]

where the sections of the main page are referenced into the definition of the class A, although they are not related.

If I change the `### First part` and `### Second part` by `\section One First part` and `\secion Two Second part` the issue diseapears, but the title are way to big and I prefer to use the markdown syntax for this Introduction.

Is this a bug or if not how shall I modify my files ?

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? With the current doxygen version (1.9.7)  I don't see the problem.

Comment: Good news ! @albert I use 1.8.17. I am upgrading and let you know.

Comment: It is gone ! Thank you @albert

Answer (score 0):

Solution: upgrade du 1.9.7 at least.